# How to get all words with specific length that doesn't contain number?

Tags: python, regex

I have an input (including unicode):

`s = "Question1: a12 is the number of a, b1 is the number of cầu thủ"`

I want to get all words that contain no number and have more than 2 chars, desire output:

`['is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'cầu', 'thủ']`.

I've tried

`re.compile('[\w]{2,}').findall(s)`

and got

`'Question1', 'a12', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'b1', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'cầu', 'thủ'`

Is there any way to get only words with no number in it?

Comment: Yes, use `re.compile(r'\b[^\W\d_]{2,}\b').findall(s)`

Comment: thanks, it works! Pls put it into an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = "Question1: a12 is the number of a, b1 is the number of cầu thủ"
print(re.compile(r'\b[^\W\d_]{2,}\b').findall(s))
# => ['is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'cầu', 'thủ']
```

Or, if you only want to limit to ASCII only letter words with minimum 2 letters:

```
print(re.compile(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b').findall(s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/z3c4BJ)

**Details**

- To match only letters, you need to use `[^\W\d_]` (or `r'[a-zA-Z]` ASCII-only variation)
- To match whole words, you need word boundaries, `\b`
- To make sure you are defining word boundaries and not backspace chars in the regex pattern, use a raw string literal, `r'...'`.

So, `r'\b[^\W\d_]{2,}\b'` defines a regex that matches a word boundary, two or more letters and then asserts that there is no word char right after these two letters.

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.isalpha`:

```
s = "Question1: a12 is the number of a, b1 is the number of cầu thủ"
[c for c in re.findall('\w{2,}', s) if c.isalpha()]
```

Output:

```
['is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'is', 'the', 'number', 'of', 'cầu', 'thủ']
```